# "Gnome Do" stops working

Tags: gnome, gnome-do

After one or two times I use Gnome Do, it stops working.  Yet it does not give out an error message.  I currently have it configured to pop up when with then <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> key combination.  I have to constantly go to the menu and activate it again.

Comment: Are you running gnome-do from the terminal? There might be some clue as to what's happening if you exit gnome-do, then start it again in the terminal.  At your name prompt, just type gnome-do and keep the terminal up and see what output it spits out.

Comment: great idea.  I'll try it later.

Comment: `gnome-do` crashes for me quite frequently too. Sometimes it just lags out but I just Alt+F2 and load it up again. If it's lagging this won't do anything but otherwise it should pop up.

Comment: I got the same problem too, sometimes the pop-up appear but doesnt do nothing when i write the query strings; This problem only happen on my notebook with ubuntu 64bit

Comment: if you run it from CLI gnome-do --debug will give the traces, that will should give more insight into the problem.

Comment: @gamerchick02: Your idea seems to have worked.  I found some plug-ins that were not configured correctly.  A

Comment: Good to hear it worked.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like the idea of running Gnome-do from the terminal, one way to figure out what is happening is to start it as `gnome-do > ~/.dolog.txt` and read that file when do crashes.
What this does it divert the output of gnome-do (read the debugging information) to the file dolog.txt. This file will be found in your home directory, as in /home/username/dolog.txt

You may file a bug against gnome-do with that file on [Launchpad](http://bugs.launchpad.net) to help fix it.

I am also having some problems with gnome-do crashing that way as well, and maybe with all of our inputs, the devs will be able to solve them.

As far as your other problem, which is restarting gnome-do once it crashes, you can always try this workaround that I found quite helpful:
Assign a shortcut key to restarting gnome-do, such as Ctrl+Shift+Space and use that instead to relaunch it.

An easy way would be to launch `gconf-editor`

then navigate to apps->metacity->global_keybindings and assign the value `<Control><Shift><Space>` to run_command_1

and then go to apps->metacity->keybinding_commands and type `exec gnome-do > ~/dolog.txt` as the value of command_1

Now when gnome-do crashes, you will have an easy way to restart it (Ctrl+Shift+Space) instead of going into the menu again...
And since that shortcut is so close to the original shortcut for summoning gnome-do in the first place, it has the added advantage of being easy to remember!

Comment: I second filing a bug with the gnome-do on Launchpad.

Comment: I guess they already have one related to that: "Do Crashing too much" https://bugs.launchpad.net/do/+bug/39433710

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after running the

```
gnome-do > ./dolog.txt
```

suggested by Tiede, I got the following error

```
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

googling 'SIGABRT gnome-do mono' gives some background, and reinstalling mono seems to be the key. The following worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mono-2.0-gac mono-gac mono-runtime
```

Comment: That should be `sudo apt-get ...`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Matthew, I made the change in my comment

Answer (score 0):

If you've just upgraded to a new version of Ubuntu, and you're now having problems with Gnome-Do in dock mode, from personal experience I'd suggest reinstalling Do. I had major compatibility problems with it immediately after upgrading to Karmic, and a reinstall fixed the problem.